# Avoid re-creating body component on each render of react-modal

Tags: reactjs

I'm using [this lib](https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-lalande-cg2yo?file=/src/App.js) to create a modal

I have 3 components: `Table`, `Modal` and `List`

`Table` has `Modal` (a custom `React Modal`), and the body of `Modal` will be `List`.
Now the problem is, `List` has some functions which change the states of `Table`, so when I do something that can make `Table`'s state change, `Table` and `Modal` will be re-rendered when `Modal` is re-rendered, it re-creates a new `List` which leads to lost all stuffs I'm doing with `List`.

Here is a simple version of my app. [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-lalande-cg2yo?file=/src/App.js)

Now I don't want `List` to be re-created each time `Modal` is re-rendered. Is there any way to archive that? (I don't want to create a modal myself or use global state management in this case)

```
import { useEffect, useMemo, useState } from "react";
import ReactModal from "react-modal";

ReactModal.setAppElement("#root");

const List = ({ onClick }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("List is mounted");
  }, []);

  return <button onClick={onClick}>Click me!</button>;
};

const Modal = ({ state, body, isOpen }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Modal is re-rendered");
  });

  return (
    <div
      id="react modal wrapper"
      style={{
        display: `${isOpen ? "block" : "none"}`
      }}
    >
      <ReactModal isOpen={isOpen}>
        <div>
          state is {state}
          <br />
          {body}
        </div>
      </ReactModal>
    </div>
  );
};

const Table = ({ state, onClick, isOpen }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Table is re-rendered");
  });

  const memorizedList = useMemo(() => <List onClick={onClick} />, []);

  return (
    <div>
      state: {state}
      <Modal state={state} body={memorizedList} isOpen={isOpen} />
    </div>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(1);

  const onClick = () => setState((v) => v + 1);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={onClick}>Change state</button>
      <Table state={state} onClick={onClick} isOpen={state % 2 === 0} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Please share your code here on SO and not as a link to codesandbox

Comment: The code is a little bit long, and it's just a simple version of my app, so I think it's better to attract a codesandbox link so people can view, fork, and edit themselves